# grabbing information off answer sites

Tags: java, string, web

First off let me say language of preference is Java but any language is acceptable for the answer since I know most languages.

Question: Say I have a link, http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140218053709AAM0WfI (random link for this example). Is there any possible way to get the title of the question and store it in a string, then get what he typed as the description for the question(aka this section here) and store it in a separate string? I know how to grab strings from a site but the problem I run into is that I keep grabbing answers aswell as the question.

Additional details.

1. I will not know the specific yahoo answer ahead of time, so the code
   needs to be able to work with all basic questions (aka ones without
   picture or other complications).
2. Code needs to work with all question/answer forum kinda sites not just yahoo.

Not asking anyone to write entire code or anything, I know that is not how site works. Just is there any specific functions that can easily obtain this information?

Comment: You could look into a library such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). It should take care of most of the nitty-gritty parts of crawling a site, and enable you to focus on extracting the information you want.

Comment: did you try beautiful soup as i mentioned in my answer???

Answer (score 0):

What you want is  data scraping. You can use Beautiful Soup for that purpose. below is the link of one of the tutorials.

http://kochi-coders.com/2011/05/30/lets-scrape-the-page-using-python-beautifulsoup/